# Cannot locate webjars with SpringBoot application running on WebSphere

Tags: java, spring-boot, websphere, webjars

I have been trying to host Spring Boot application on WebSphere server.

Versions :

- SpringBoot 2.1.6.RELEASE
- WebSphere Liberty 19.0.0.6 with JavaEE 8
- webjars-locator 0.36

The app was successfuly deployed on standalone Tomcat 9.0.22 and webjars could be resolved there. However for WebSphere I receive an error when trying to access webjars from `html` page :

```
2019-08-05 10:43:11.839 DEBUG 1 --- [ecutor-thread-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/appcontext/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js", parameters={}
2019-08-05 10:43:11.845 DEBUG 1 --- [ecutor-thread-6] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"]
2019-08-05 10:43:11.849 DEBUG 1 --- [ecutor-thread-6] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2019-08-05 10:43:11.849 DEBUG 1 --- [ecutor-thread-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
```

And the `webjars` pattern was successfuly mapped by Spring :

```
2019-08-05 10:43:09.039 DEBUG 1 --- [ecutor-thread-6] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Patterns [/webjars/**, /**] in 'resourceHandlerMapping'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this is to add `classloading` entry, with `useJarUrls` attribute set to `true`, to WebSphere `server.xml` file :

```
<server description="myServer">
    <featureManager>
        <feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
    </featureManager>
    <classloading useJarUrls="true"/> <!-- this line was added -->
    <httpEndpoint httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" host="*" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>
</server>
```

This [`IBM support issue`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM99378) was particulary helpful in solving this problem.